# Web API 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-405

Still haven't found a solution that will work for me on this site. Here is my web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

I remove the WebDAV module and the handler. I have included the "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" and even added the custom headers. Why would I still be seeing this error? TIA

Comment: I am also getting crazy and created a new thread just now.